# How can I create child elements dynamically and pass properties for them from the parent component In Angular

Tags: angular, data-binding, parent-child, parent, creation

I want to have my parent html file like :

```
<div #parent>
<child id="1" [isclicked]="false"></child>
<child id="2"  [isclicked]="false"></child>
<child id="3"  [isclicked]="false"></child>
<child id="4"  [isclicked]="false"></child>
<child id="5"  [isclicked]="false"></child>
<child id="6"  [isclicked]="false"></child>
</div>
```

But I would like to do it dynamically from the TS - appending all my childs inside the div #parent

By looking over in the internet, I've found something like

```
@ViewChild('parent', {read: ViewContainerRef})
 parent: ViewContainerRef;
 
 constructor (private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
 const childComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent); 
 const anotherChildComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AnotherChildComponent)
 
 setTimeout(()=>{
 // at this point we want the "child" component to be rendered into the app.component:
  this.parent.createComponent(childComponent);
 },1000);
```

Which works, but I didn't find how to also pass my id.
I believe I need to have

```
Input() id: number
Input() isclicked: boolean
```

inside the child Typescript since they get sent from the parent, but I don't know where I should add the code to bind the id and "`isclicked`" property from the child element creation

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#loading-components) explains. Basically you need to do the following:

```
const componentRef = this.parent.createComponent(childComponent);

componentRef.instance.id = someId;
componentRef.instance.isClicked = someIsClicked;
```

Then in the child component class have

```
@Input() id: number;
@Input() isClicked: boolean;
```

And in the template:

```
... [isClicked]="isClicked" ...
```

etc.